# C# file path is not storing in the database. it is storing "System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload" in the database

Tags: mysql, asp.net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
```

> Unable to correctly store the file path

```
public partial class UploadedFile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=cook;Initial Catalog=MIS;Integrated Security=True");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void StartUpLoad()
    {
        //get the file name of the posted image
        string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();

        //now we will set the image path
        string filePath = "ImageStorage/" + fileName;

        //then save it to the folder

        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));


        //now get the size in bytes of the file
        //int fileSize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;

        //validate the posted file before saving 

        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null && FileUpload1.FileName != "")
        {
            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 8120)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Alert", "alert('File is too big')", true);
            }
            else
            {
                //save the file
                //call the method to execute  insertion of data to the database
                ExecuteInsert(filePath);
                Label.Text = "File" +  fileName  + "Successfully uploaded";


            }
        }


    }


    private string GetConnectionString()
    {
        //sets the connection string from web.config
        return
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDataEntries"].ConnectionString;
    }



    private void ExecuteInsert(string path)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());


        string sql = "INSERT INTO JobPortalDatabase (FirstName,LastName,StreetAddress,EmailAddress,ContactNumber,PositionAppliedFor,NameoftheCompany,AddressofCompany,NameofSupervisor,EnterContactNumberofSupervisor,EmailAddressofSupervisor,DescribeYourDuties,NameoftheCompany1,AddressofCompany1,NameofSupervisor1,EnterContactNumberofSupervisor1,EmailAddressofSupervisor1,DescribeYourDuties1,FilePath,FileName) VALUES  ('" + TextBox1.Text + "' , '" + TextBox2.Text + "' , '" + TextBox3.Text + "' , '" + TextBox4.Text + "' , '" + TextBox5.Text + "' , '" + TextBox6.Text + "' , '" + TextBox7.Text + "' , '" + TextBox8.Text + "' , '" + TextBox9.Text + "' , '" + TextBox10.Text + "' , '" + TextBox11.Text + "' , '" + TextBox12.Text + "' , '" + TextBox13.Text + "' , '" + TextBox14.Text + "' , '" + TextBox15.Text + "' , '" + TextBox16.Text + "' , '" + TextBox17.Text + "' , '" + TextBox18.Text + "' , '" + FileUpload1+ "' , '" + FileUpload1.FileName + "')";

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            //SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];


            //param[0] = new SqlParameter("@FilePath", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);

            //param[0].Value = path;

            //for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
            //{
            //    cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
            //}
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert error";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();

        }


    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartUpLoad();

    }
    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Response.Redirect("PersonalInformation.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection.  And your `catch` block is throwing away useful information about the exception (and adding nothing, it should probably just be removed entirely).  As for the problem itself, you're using the `FileUpload` variable as a string in your SQL query.  That's not a string.  And the string value for an object is the class name.  You're already storing the file name in another field, so what are you *trying* to store in that field?

Comment: FileUpload1.FileName replace this with path in your ExecuteInsert method.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `FilePath` property in your `INSERT` statement.

Incorrectly, you have `+ FileUpload1+` by itself (in the second last item)
You need a function or property call that returns a String for this item like

`+ FileUpload1.FilePath +`

or

`+ IO.Path(FileUpload1.FileName) +`